# Why reactiveTimer( ) throw error since shiny_1.1.0

Tags: r, shiny

I use reactiveTimer() in app and since the upgrade of shiny 1.1.0 my app throws an error. I know it's possible to use invalidLater() insted of reactiveTimer() but i don't find any explication in [the upgrade note](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.1.0/upgrade.html) of shiny that explain this behaviour.

This code don't throw error with shiny 1.0.5 but throw one since 1.1.0

```
# Create timer with reactiveTimer work with shiny 1.0.5 but not with 
# shiny 1.1.0.

## Install older version of shiny 
#devtools::install_version('shiny', version = '1.0.5')

library(shiny)

## Create a timer function
auto_invalide <- reactiveTimer(1000)

## Void UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(

)

## Minimal server ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  ## Print some stuff every time timer trigger
   observe({
     auto_invalide()
     print("auto invalided")
   })
}

## Run application ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks for any advice or clues for solution.

Comment: Huh, this looks like a bug. You might want to file an issue at https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues

Comment: Thank you for the advice i file [one](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2228)